# Rich calender field

Tags: javascript, richfaces

I'm using rich calender to select a date. we have 2 date fields from and to dates. once date selected for the from date automatically to date should populate with same date please help me in resolving this. attaching code snippet

i'm not getting how to proceed further.

```
<h:outputLabel id="label3"/>
<rich:calendar id="vdFrom" inputStyle="width:60px" enableManualInput="true" oninputkeyup="checkdate(this,'date')" 
               value="#{mcifTransMBean.valueFromDate}" datePattern="MM/dd/yy" ondateselected="updateToClndDate('mcifTransForm:vdFrom','mcifTransForm:vdTo');" 
               immediate="true" >
    <f:facet name="optionalHeader"> 
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%" style="text-align:center;height:5px" columnClasses="width100, fake">
            <h:outputText value="Select Value Date From" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </f:facet>

    <a4j:support id="vd1" event="ondateselected" reRender="vdTo" />
    <a4j:support id="vd2" event="onchanged" reRender="date" />

    </rich:calendar>

<h:outputText id="text7" styleClass="outputText" value=" To "></h:outputText>
<rich:calendar inputStyle="width:60px" id="vdTo" enableManualInput="true" oninputkeyup="checkdate(this,'date')" 
               value="#{mcifTransMBean.valueToDate}" datePattern="MM/dd/yy" >
    <f:facet name="optionalHeader">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="updateto" width="100%" style="text-align:center;hieght:5px"columnClasses="width100, fake">
            <h:outputText id="opupdateto"  value="Select Value Date To" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </f:facet>
</rich:calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us what your `updateToClndDate` function looks like.
Anyway, you can set the value on the second calendar like this:

```
<rich:calendar id="vdFrom" ondateselect="#{rich:component('vdTo')}.selectDate(#{rich:component('vdFrom')}.getSelectedDate())" />

<rich:calendar id="vdTo"/>
```